# How do I show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ is concave using $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\geq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$ is concave using $f(\frac{x+y}{2})\geq\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ and not the second derivative argument. However, I get into the following trouble: \begin{align} f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}+1}\\ &=\dfrac{\sqrt{x+y+2}}{\sqrt{2}}\\ &=\dfrac{\sqrt{(x+1)+(y+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}\\ &\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{(x+1)}+\sqrt{(y+1)}}{\sqrt{2}} \quad \text{since $\sqrt{x}$ is subadditive}\\&=\dfrac{f(x)+f(y)}{\sqrt{2}}. \end{align} Please what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Your very first line has "$+1$" under the radical, while the function in the title does not...? That said, nothing in your argument is wrong, strictly speaking, it's just not sharp enough to prove what you want. Squaring the inequality you want to prove should help.

Comment: It was a mistake. The function is $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\geq 0$.
Using the inequality $\sqrt{xy} \leq (x+y)/2$ you get
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{x + y + 2\sqrt{xy}}{4}
\leq \frac{x+y + 2 \frac{x+y}{2}}{4} = \frac{x+y}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This actually solved my problem